# ScrollView in a anchorlayout. python. kivy

Tags: python, scrollview, kivy

[practice screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7xOJ.png)

This is from the .py file

The screens are controlled by screen manager as you can see

```
class Practice_Page(Screen):
    pass

class PracticeList(BoxLayout):
    def practicelist(ScrollView):

        practicelist.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
```

.KV file:

```
<Practice_page>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'background1.png'


    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        PracticeList:
            size: 900,30
            size_hint: None,None
            do_scroll_x: False        
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                padding: 10
                cols: 1
                Button:
                    text: 'The Real Number System'           
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'open_topics'
                Button:
                    text: 'Absolute Value'
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'open_practice'
                Button:
                    text: 'Operations W/ Integers & Fractions'           
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'open_topics'                    
                Button:
                    text: 'Operations W/ Zero'
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'open_formulas'
```

I have about 30 more buttons. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, any help or suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: Try to explain more, I have no idea right now what your issue is. If you explain it better then I might be able to help you.

Comment: @MatthiasSchreiber as you can see from the image, all the buttons are stacked on top of each other so you can see them.. I want to add a scrollview to the anchorlayout so user can scroll through a list of topic names. Thank you again, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'center'
    ScrollView:
        #size: 900,30
        size: self.size
        #do_scroll_x: False        
        GridLayout:
           # orientation: 'vertical'
            #padding: 10
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            cols: 1
            Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                text: 'The Real Number System'           
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'open_topics'
            Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                text: 'Absolute Value'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'open_practice'
            Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                text: 'Operations W/ Integers & Fractions'           
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'open_topics'                    
            Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                text: 'Operations W/ Zero'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'open_formulas'

            ##MORE BTNS
```

For anyone who needs it.